# React Native trigger press event except child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My use-case is trigger something when click parent component (`TouchableOpacity` for example), but trigger nothing when click children component (`Screen` and others for Example). My case is same like prevent bubbling on web. From docs I've read said that it should use `onStartShouldSetResponderCapture`, but I still don't understand for the usage. Below is the snippet.

```
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={() => alert('tes')}
  >
    <Screen style={styles.screenContainer} onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() => false}>
      <Title>Edit Nama Restoran</Title>
      <Divider styleName='line' />

      <TextInput
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        value={value}
        onChangeText={value => this.setState({ value })}
        onSubmitEditing={this.handleSubmit}
      />

      <View styleName='horizontal' style={styles.nameContainer}>
        <Button styleName='confirmation dark' onPress={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Text>UPDATE</Text>
        </Button>
        <Button styleName='confirmation' onPress={onClose}>
          <Text>CLOSE</Text>
        </Button>
      </View>
    </Screen>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

**EDIT:**

Below is an illustration of my case.

If I click overlay (outside of `<Screen>`), it triggers an alert (expected).

If I click white dialog (`<Screen>` and children inside), it triggers an alert too (unexpected). What I need is not trigger alert when click `<Screen>`.

[image: Illustation]

Answer (score 0):

Updated to show how to do with a modal:

```
<Modal
  visible={this.state.modalVisible}
  onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
 >
  <TextInput
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    value={value}
    onChangeText={value => this.setState({ value })}
    onSubmitEditing={this.handleSubmit}
  />
</Modal>
```

Not sure if this is the right snippet from your code, but basically the part you want to pop up, pull it out from the touchable opacity and wrap a modal around it. Then on click have it visible/invisible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it didn't work. See my edited post: I have added a GIF illustration to cover what I need :)

Comment: Ohh I see now, I would turn wrap that textInput in a modal, remove it as a child and have it visibile/invisible on button click. As a modal, it shouldn't let you be able to select views behind it.

Comment: Would you mind if you edit your post and include the snippet on there? A snippet can help me to understand what you mean. No need for detail snippet, because I understand how to trigger visible/invisible on button click. I just don't understand on tag structure. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems I should delete TouchableOpacity from the structure, right? Something that make me confused: `Then on click have it visible/invisible`, where is `onClick` props I should include? <Modal> didn't have `onClick` props

Comment: Think of TouchableOpacity like a button, you should only use it if you want to simulate something like a button click with an onlick response when they do. For the modal, you will have it in your render with the visible property as something like this.state.modalVisible. Elsewhere you will have button or something that will change this state to true and you're modal will be visible. It doesn't have to be an onclick feature. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Hmm something that I still didn't understand is: how to trigger dismiss modal if and only if I click overlay (black semi-transparent area), and don't dismiss modal if I click white dialog (see my posted GIF), but I still be able to click Button or TextInput inside modal to do something (not dismiss). I just wrap TouchableOpacity inside Modal to trigger dismiss, but it's also dismiss modal if I click white-box' View (which is unexpected on my case). I need a solution to not trigger dismiss when click white-box' View. Sorry if I can't explain clearly, my english is not really good :)